# return a list or string up to first occurrence of that object

Tags: python

I have to write a function that takes a list(or string) and and object and returns the copy of the list up to but not including the first occurrence of that object, or all the elements if that object is not in the list.

I know I have to use a loop here but what I'm confused at is lists and strings use different methods for finding the index of that object. How can I use that with the loops to get my function up to the first occurrence of that object.

```
def up_to_first(item, element):
    if type(item) == list:
        index_of_element = item.index(element)
        res = [ ]
        for i in range(0, index_of_element):
            sliced_list = item[0 : index_of_element]

    return sliced_list
```

Comment: Please show your code attempt and we can further guide you in the right direction.

Comment: In addition to showing the code that you have tried so far, could you also give example input and expected output? What kind of `object` are you referring to? A string, or could it be anything?

Comment: how can i add code

Comment: You paste it in, then you can highlight all of it and use the `{}` button or CTRL-K to format it

Comment: Also, lists and strings *do not* use different methods for finding the index of an object: they both use `index()`

Comment: what i mean is if i have a list for ex: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and i want to know the index of 3 how can i do that

Comment: Haven't you already done it? `iterable.index(item)`

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].index(3) `

Comment: but it dosen't work for strings, my code should work for both lists and strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
def up_to_first(seq, obj):
    if obj not in seq:
        return seq
    return seq[:seq.index(obj)]
```

This will return the [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) `seq` if `obj` is not in that sequence, and will return the sequence up to, but not including `obj` otherwise. However, this function as it is will break if you are not careful about types. For example, it will work if you are looking for `5` in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (and return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), but will raise an error if you look for `5` in a string.

```
>>> up_to_first([1, 2, 3], 3)
[1, 2]
>>> up_to_first('abcdef', 'd')
'abc'
>>> up_to_first([1, 2, 3], 'a')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> up_to_first('abcdef', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../.../test.py", line 2, in up_to_first
    if obj not in seq:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: it works fine for strings also

Comment: @SyedNaqi, yes, but it will not work if `seq` is a string and `obj` is not. With a little work this case could be handled as well though. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) already has a feature for this:

```
def seq_upto(seq, obj):
    return itertools.takewhile(lambda el: el is not obj, iter(seq))
```

I'm unclear if you want to match on the *identity* of an object or its equality (as in the `__eq__` operator), but in the above lambda I'm using identity.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def seq_upto(seq, obj):
...     return itertools.takewhile(lambda el: el is not obj, iter(seq))
...
>>> class foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> y=seq_upto([0,1,2,3,4,foo,4,3,2], foo)
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y=seq_upto(range(5), foo)
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```